# SELECT por palavra no sql server sem utilizar o Full Text Index

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso fazer uma consulta numa tabela com as seguintes palavras:

> "Hoje o Dia ficou chuvoso"

Preciso pesquisar por qualquer uma dessas palavras. Por exemplo se achou a palavra *"dia"*, teria que me retornar o registro. Ou seja, qualquer uma dessas palavras que achar ele teria que me retornar.

Preciso também fazer uma pesquisa que me retorne todas essas palavras pesquisadas por exemplo:

> "dia hoje chuvoso"

se o registro dessa tabela tiver essas três palavras não necessariamente nessa ordem teria que trazer.

Estou quebrando a cabeça de como fazer isso. Ah não posso utilizar o `FUllText` pois teria que pedir autorização até pro PAPA pois esse recurso esta desabilitado em Produção. Estou utilizando o SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

---

Obrigado pelas respostas consegui avançar um pouco fiz mais ou menos assim criando uma tabela temporária pra jogar minha string de pesquisa e separando as palavras por espaço. porém ainda estou com problemas

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @ARRAY VARCHAR(8000), @DELIMITADOR VARCHAR(100), @S VARCHAR(8000)

-- VALORES PASSADOS PARA A VARIAVEL @ARRAY
SELECT @ARRAY = 'hoje o dia ficou chuvoso'
-- SETANDO O DELIMITADOR
SELECT @DELIMITADOR = ' '

IF LEN(@ARRAY) > 0 SET @ARRAY = @ARRAY + @DELIMITADOR 
CREATE TABLE #ARRAY(ITEM_ARRAY VARCHAR(8000))

WHILE LEN(@ARRAY) > 0
BEGIN
   SELECT @S = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@ARRAY, 1, CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @ARRAY) - 1))
   INSERT INTO #ARRAY (ITEM_ARRAY) VALUES (@S)
   SELECT @ARRAY = SUBSTRING(@ARRAY, CHARINDEX(@DELIMITADOR, @ARRAY) + 1, LEN(@ARRAY))
END




-- Qualquer uma das palavras
SELECT  DISTINCT * FROM TABELA_A a JOIN #ARRAY ON CAMPO1 like '%' + ITEM_ARRAY + '%';

DROP TABLE #ARRAY

SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Nesse Exemplo ele retorna qualquer uma das palavras que estiver na minha tabela temporária Até aí OK. Porém ele confunde a palavra (dia por diagnostico) isso em função ao uso do Like. Porém não sei como substituir isso. Além do mais não consegui fazer retornar SOMENTE os registros que contenham todas as palavras que estão na tabela temporária.

São duas coisas. 
Primeiro: Retornar qualquer uma das palavras que estão na tabela temporária
Segundo: Retornar todas as palavras que estão na tabela temporária

Basicamente estou pegando a TABELA A (TEMPORARIA) e comparando com a tabela B e retornando os registros da tabela B conforme os critérios que falei

Comment: Eu entendi que essas palavras 'hoje', 'dia', 'chuvoso' que você usou como exemplo podem estar contidas na descrição do item. E que a descrição pode, inclusive, conter mais de uma palavra. Isto esta certo?

Comment: @FernandoL: Você pode acrescentar tabela e trigger no banco de dados de desenvolvimento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo essa resposta do [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444300/search-for-whole-word-match-with-sql-server-like-pattern)

Uma vez que você não pode utilizar Full text, isso deve ajudar

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE '.' + column + '.' LIKE '%[^a-z]parameters[^a-z]%'`

**EDIT**
Dei uma pesquisada maior e acho que isso resolve seu problema
troque `[tabela]` pela sua tabela e `[campo]` pelo seu campo

```
declare @List NVARCHAR(MAX), @Delim CHAR(1)
set @List = 'Hoje o Dia ficou chuvoso' 

set @Delim = ',' 
set @List = REPLACE(@List, ' ', @Delim)

SELECT      * 
FROM        [tabela] 
INNER JOIN  (
    -- USED TO SPLIT THE VALUES INTO A NEW TABLE
        SELECT 
            [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
            CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
        FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
            FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
            WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
            AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
) B ON  '.' + [campo] + '.' LIKE '%[^a-z]'+ B.VALUE +'[^a-z]%'
```

Comment: Legal essa opção é bem melhor.

Comment: Cara muito bom. Obrigado estava quebrando a cabeça me ajudou muito

Answer (score 0):

```
TABLE = sua tabela, FIELD = campo que deseja filtrar, keyword = palavras chaves(chuvoso, dia ,...).
```

Lembrando que `%` substitui o resto da frase, e por isso tem que ser colocado antes e depois da palavra chave.

```
SELECT FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE 
  FIELD4 LIKE '%KEYWORD1%' OR 
  FIELD4 LIKE '%keyWord2%'
```